# Use Asp:Gridview As Data Entry

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, webforms, aspxgridview

Is it possible to use an asp:gridview for data entry when the grid has no data source....then when a user clicks the submit button the data gets bound to a data table?

I tried to open this project - but it fails every time.  Maybe because lowest version of VS I have is 2017?

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8301/How-to-convert-DataGrid-into-Data-Entry-Form

Comment: very likely yes. show what you tried and where you're stuck, otherwise there will hardly be any useful answers. Have a look if [this does what you need](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24144932/1132334)

Comment: no offense, but "fails every time" is not a problem description. is there an error message we can use to find out more about the problem?

Comment: @dlatikay - Error message solution failed to load

Comment: that's just a couple of cs and resx files. open the csproj instead of the solution, if that fails too then create a new solution with the appropriate project type (ASP.NET) and just add those source files from their zip. don't forget to "unblock" the zip after the download, if you use an operating system susceptible to this disease. if it turns out to be a problem specific to packaging or versioning, contact the author at codeproject instead.

Comment: @dlatikay - the link is from 2004 - was not sure if there was a more efficient way since it is now 2018

Comment: yeah that's a couple of visual studio versions gone by indeed. my honest opinion (therefore I don't feel like writing up an answer here) is that if you want to modernize, do not use a grid view at all. if you need to, there are some answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44660956/1132334) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23772591/1132334)

Comment: @dlatikay - what would you recommend using instead of a grid view?